# How do you find the median normalization for a large dataset when there is multiple sections that you have to normalize data

Tags: r

My dataset has over 11,000 cells. These cells are divided into 80 slides(based on the information they got from the microscope slides in the lab) and these slides are then divided into a few hundred columns. I'm supposed to find the median normalization of each individual slides for all 80 of the slides. I'm really confused on how to do the normalization when there are multiple normalizations to be done within one excel sheet. I've inserted a picture of what a sample of my data would look like in case my explanation was confusing

[SAMPLE DATA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HzbrM.png)

Comment: please provide some example data.

Comment: [You should not post code or sample data as an image because ...](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/1422451)

Comment: please provide coding attempt, otherwise this is a broad question.